# 2d output of 3d data not via block number but value of column

Tags: 3d, output, 2d, gnuplot

I have some 3d data like so:

```
0.0  1. 2.
0.0  2. 7.
0.0  3. 1.1

0.1  1. 8.
0.1  2. 5.
0.1  3. 1.

0.2  1. 6.
0.2  2. 3.
0.2  3. 4.
```

The first line being the "t" (time) axis, second column "x" and the third the actual value of my variable.
Of course, the above is schematic.

Now, I would like to only plot the block with "time" t=0.2.
With the above, I could simply look and see which block number this corresponds to and I could just use `every :::2::2` in this case.
The problem is that my actual file has tens of thousand's of lines, making up a few thousands' of blocks.
If I want to only plot a block corresponding to a certain time, it would be very tedious counting what block number a certain time corresponds to.
Thus, is there a way for me to give gnuplot what "time" (first column as in the above example) I would like it to plot the corresponding block; and gnuplot figures out internally the associated block?
You may assume that I know the exact time, although, optimally, I would like to give gnuplot a time t, then gnuplot looks up the first column of the file and outputs the block which's time is closest to the given time t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the ternary operator as filter:

`($1==0.2 ? $2 : NaN)`

in words: 
if the first column is equal to 0.2, take the value of the second column as x-value, otherwise take NaN (which will not be plotted.)

**Code:**

```
### filter data
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0.0  1. 2.
0.0  2. 7.
0.0  3. 1.1

0.1  1. 8.
0.1  2. 5.
0.1  3. 1.

0.2  1. 6.
0.2  2. 3.
0.2  3. 4.

0.3  2. 3.
0.3  1. 2.
0.3  4. 5.
EOD

plot $Data u ($1==0.2 ? $2 : NaN) : 3 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "red"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]